# how to select a random name from a list of names saved on a note pad file on my computer

Tags: python-3.x

```
import random
count = 0

f = open("//ct68-fs-01/cats canterbury$/Users/Students/je20808/My Documents/anyfile.txt","r")

while 1:
    n = (f.readline())
    if not n :break
    count = (count + 1)

s = random.randrange(1,count)

f = open("//ct68-fs-01/cats canterbury$/Users/Students/je20808/My Documents/anyfile.txt","r")
n = (f.readline(s))
print(n)
```

sadly it just shows the first name in the list please help with this.

Comment: done any basic debugging, like seeing what the values of `count` and `s` are?

Comment: You should split this into more, shorter functions. E.g. one to get a list of names from a file, and one to make a random selection from a list.

Comment: Are you trying to translate this from another scripting language?  As written it doesn't make much Python sense.

Answer (score 2):

`f.readline(s)` doesn't read the `s`th line; it reads a single line, up to a maximum of `s` bytes. You'll have to save the lines in an array or something (which can be done in your while loop), and then pick the `s`th element of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Following @jonrsharpe suggestion, you should break this up to descrete tasks via functions:

```
import random

def loadNames():
    with open(NAMELIST, 'r') as inFile:
        return [name for name in inFile.read().strip()]

def getRandomName():
    return random.choice(MYNAMES)

NAMELIST = '/path/to/namefile/namefile.txt'
MYNAMES = loadNames()

print getRandomName()
```